# Problem using Azure Blob Storage to save user conversations

Tags: azure, botframework

I'm getting an error with the code below when I'm adding the Azure Blob Storage as a singleton. I think I've installed the dependencies correctly as:

```
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Azure" Version="4.6.3"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Blobs" Version="12.2.0"/>
```

in the .csproj file. However the error I am getting relates t the AzureBlobStorage object in the code below;

```
<!-- language: c# -->

namespace Microsoft.BotBuilderSamples
{
    public class Startup
    {
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Create the storage we'll be using for User and Conversation state. (Memory is great for testing purposes.)
            var storageAccount = "connection_string_from_azure";
            var storageContainer = "mybotstorage";

            services.AddSingleton<IStorage>(new AzureBlobStorage(storageAccount, storageContainer));

            // Create the User state. (Used in this bot's Dialog implementation.)
            services.AddSingleton<UserState>();

            // Create the Conversation state. (Used by the Dialog system itself.)
            services.AddSingleton<ConversationState>();

            // Other Startup things
        }
    }
}
```

The error is:

> The type or namespace name 'AzureBlobStorage' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [CoreBot]

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where did you get this code from? It is obviously missing `AzureBlobStorage`.

Comment: I'm using the echo bot sample from Azure and trying to implement an Azure storage function through local development from an online tutorial

Comment: Can you share the link of that tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, I had to open the bot in MS Visual Studio and install the Azure dependency. I was editing in MS Visual Studio Code, so not sure how I could've done a work around from there.